# Error in boost library

Tags: c++, boost, g++, gsl

I'm trying to compile my project, it contains many files and it need 3 libraries gsl,libxml,boost
when i give the terminal the g++ command on ubuntu 14.04LTS

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/gsl main.cpp YUNucNet.cpp src/*.cpp -lxml2 -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

it gives me these error

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:34:0,
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected ‘}’ before end of line
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
                                 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected unqualified-id before end of line
/usr/include/c++/4.8/typeinfo:39:37: error: expected declaration before end of line
```

what would be the problem ???? I can't get it .

thanx

Answer (score 0):

default is a c++11 token.
You need to compile with -std=c++0x or something similar. Make sure your gcc is new enough to support such things.

Comment: how i can do that ??

Comment: You are really not making it easy for you...

g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/gsl main.cpp YUNucNet.cpp src/*.cpp -lxml2 -lgsl -lm -lgslcblas -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
As I suggested

Comment: still it gives me these Errors

In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:426,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:38,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/math.h:28:1: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
 __BEGIN_DECLS
 ^
main.cpp:13:2: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 };